# why changing an array effects a different array

Tags: android, arrays, object

I put an array as part of an object and have an arraylist of them. Once i make the object the varibles that i used as the constucter for the object once they change that shouldnt change the object right? What i dont understand even more is i take the array from my object and thats right but then i modify a different array and it modify the one that i got back from my object.

```
                String [] tempnums1 = Contacts.get(0).getNumbers();
                Log.d("array", "tempnums is " + tempnums1[0]);
                numbers[0] = "ive changes";
                Log.d("array", "tempnums again is " + tempnums1[0]);
                String [] tempnums2 = Contacts.get(0).getNumbers();
                Log.d("array", "tempnums2 is " + tempnums2[0]);
```

the first print is right but then i modify numbers[0] and when i print tempnums[0] out it has changed to "tempnums again is ive changed" this makes no sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to `Contacts.get(0).getNumbers()` returning the same array at each call. If that's what's going on, there is no "different array"—only one array is involved. Thus, your code would be equivalent to doing this:

```
String [] tempnums1 = Contacts.get(0).getNumbers();
Log.d("array", "tempnums is " + tempnums1[0]);
numbers[0] = "ive changes";
Log.d("array", "tempnums again is " + tempnums1[0]);
String [] tempnums2 = tempnums1;
Log.d("array", "tempnums2 is " + tempnums2[0]);
```

In particular, assigning an array value to an array variable does not make a copy of the array. You (or, rather, `getNumbers()` or your calling code) would have to do that explicitly.